What is the "question assistant" being evaluated for Staging Ground?
I noticed that in the Community Products Roadmap Update, October 2024 article that came out last week, it mentions the following in regards to questions being asked via the Staging Ground:

For askers, we are evaluating whether a question assistant can be effective to improve their drafts. This would allow askers to improve question drafts earlier in the process, while saving time for reviewers.

What is this "Question Assistant" exactly? This "smells" like it's going to use some kind of AI/LLM model to improve the quality of the post (and reminds me of the formatting assistant), however, we all know that LLM/AI content is banned across all communities, so such a tool would not be permitted. So is this more going to be more like a Stack Overflow specific Grammarly, as anything more would be breaking Stack Overflow's own rules? Can we have some context of what this Question Assistant actually is?

"What is this "Question Assistant" exactly?" Remember Clippy? Meet Asky!

I couldn't find the post at first, but I was remembering (the horrors of) the formatting assistant, @VLAZ .

Almost the first thing that was brought up on MSE as well. There is a comment from staff assuring us that it's totally different. I'm not inclined to accept it on faith, though.

Funny thing is if it was more akin to grammarly it’d be better named the same as the old one, as the old one rarely helped with formatting at all and was quite aggressive at instead assisting with content.

The roadmap was announced on Meta Stack Exchange.
The old format assistant was almost immediately brought up by Kevin B:


For askers, we are evaluating whether a question assistant can be effective to improve their drafts. This would allow askers to improve question drafts earlier in the process, while saving time for reviewers.

We’ve already been down this road, can we just go next and make real improvements to the ask wizard?

Staff member Emerson then commented on the post:

@KevinB I understand why these would be seen similarly, but as the CM who handled the Content Formatter Experiment, I can say with a high degree of confidence that this is a different approach. I know there is a post in the works that will be able to shed more light on the methodology.


It is not much of an answer but so far, this is the only information we have publicly available, as far as I know. It should at least give some context. Hopefully, we get an actual explanation.
